# Whitespace separate in c

Tags: html, c, post, cgi

I am doing a cgi. I am using POST method in the html and I receive a string from stdin in C. I would like to get the content of a file that i upload with post method. So I have to reach the  part of STDIN after Content-Type:(something) (content). The problem is that I cannot find a way on how to split on the white space.

Any thoughts?

```
 //---post functions---
    lenstr=getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
     if(lenstr == NULL || sscanf(lenstr,"%ld",&len)!=1 || len > 1048576)
    {
          printf("<P>Error in invocation - wrong FORM probably.");
        }    
     else{
     fread(input, len+1,1, stdin);
     strtok(input,":");
     strtok(NULL,":");
     strtok(NULL,"/");
     //strtok(NULL," ");
    input_p3=strtok(NULL,"");   
     len_p=strlen(input)-strlen("Content-Disposition");
     len_p3=strlen(input_p3);
     strcpy(paper->paper_file_name,input_p3);
             for(u=0;u<len_p3-len_p-2;u++){
                printf("%c",paper->paper_file_name[u]);
            }
```

If i uncomment the strtok that I have //, it does not work. But this way it prints for example for a txt file "plain (content)" and plain comes from text/plain

Comment: So the `strtok(NULL; "/");` gets you a pointer to `"text"`, then a `strtok(NULL," ");` would get you a pointer to `"plain"` if that is followed by a space. A further `strtok` would then get you to the contents.

Comment: Can you tell in what way it doesn't work? Maybe after the `plain` there is no space but a tab or a newline?

Comment: Thanks man....it was a new line and not space character!

Answer (score 2):

use `strtok` function and use `" "` as your delimiter. Successive calls to the function will return a pointer to the next token in the string so first call gives "Content-type:" then the next 2 calls will give you what you want.

Comment: @ThemisMavridis It should work show me your code as it may be incorrect.

Comment: I have updated the original post with code. If you can tell me specifically what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @ThemisMavridis You're using the wrong delimiter the next time around in the strtok call

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

But be careful since strtok has a global to indicate the current token index, so consider wrapping it in a critical section.

Comment: I have updated the original post with code. If you can tell me specifically what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Isn't the critical section control-device only useful when multi-threading? Wouldn't it have zero effect in a single-thread CGI?

Comment: @cowboydan - Okay, thank-you. Never had a situation where I needed to use them, so never bothered to really research them all that much. Just wanted to confirm what I thought I knew. Cheers. :)